# Obtain standard Input from remote process

Tags: c#, process, remote-access

I want to obtain the ***Process.StandardInput*** from a remote process via a known process id.
This is so I can input some text into the running process on another machine.

I could write a script which the remote machine could have locally to execute remotely to achieve this, however I'm wondering if there is a way I can do it directly in code from a remote location.

To be clear, I am not starting this process so I do not have the original process object or redirected input stream. It is already running.

Locally, a simplified version of the code would look something like this:

```
// These are known beforehand
int myProcessId = 1234;
string myCommand = "example";

// This is what I need
Process.GetProcessById( myProcessId ).StandardInput.WriteLine( myCommand );
```

Can this be achieved remotely with nothing more than a process id?

Comment: _To use StandardInput, you must set ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute to false, and you must set ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput to true. Otherwise, writing to the StandardInput stream throws an exception._ -  [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput)

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I would just use `Powershell` and the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet to accomplish this.